# Animate with ease full colour and zoom for image

Tags: css

I'm using [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to create a carousel of product images. I've set all slides to be grayscale then I've set the current slide to be slightly bigger and full colour, this part works.

I want to make it a bit smoother though. Instead of it jumping to full colour and being bigger, how can I ease this? It'd be nice if the colour goes from grey to full colour and the size gets bigger gradually. (And then work in the opposite direction when not the current slide)

Is that possible?

The class `slick-current` get's added to the slide as soon as it's the active one.

```
.category-gallery .slick-slide {
    zoom:1;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Old WebKit */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* New WebKit */
    filter: grayscale(100%); /* Current draft standard */
}

.category-gallery .slick-current {
    zoom:1.3!important;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0)!important; /* Old WebKit */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%)!important; /* New WebKit */
    filter: grayscale(0%)!important; /* Current draft standard */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scale()` rather than `zoom`. You can then use `transition` to animate the property changes.

I've used `:hover` here to simulate the class change:

```css
.category-gallery .slick-slide {
  transform: scale(1);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.category-gallery .slick-slide:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class='category-gallery'>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
  </div>
</div>
```